# How do I save a QByteArray in my Qt panel?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a RViz plug-in / Qt panel like in [this tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/panel_plugin_tutorial.html).

There is a `QTableWidget` in this panel and I would like to be able to save/restore the geometry when the user closes/launches again the panel/application.

My save callback looks like this:

```
void DisplayTopics::save(rviz::Config config) const
                         {
  rviz::Panel::save(config);

  QByteArray table_header_state(table_->horizontalHeader()->saveState());
  // FIXME Saves an empty string, bug in RViz?
  config.mapSetValue("table_header_state", table_header_state);
}
```

The load callback looks like:

```
void DisplayTopics::load(const rviz::Config& config)
{
  rviz::Panel::load(config);

  QVariant table_header_state_var;
  if (config.mapGetValue("table_header_state", &table_header_state_var))
  {
    if (table_header_state_var.canConvert(QMetaType::QByteArray))
    {
      QByteArray table_header_state(table_header_state_var.toByteArray());

      if (!table_header_state.isEmpty())
        table_->horizontalHeader()->restoreState(table_header_state);
    }
  }
}
```

When the config file is saved, the `table_header_state` field is empty:

```
  - Class: topics_rviz_plugin/DisplayTopics
    Name: DisplayTopics
    table_header_state: ""
```

I have tested with `qDebug` and the `QByteArray` is not empty when saving.

Why is the field empty?
Full code example is available here: https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/topics_rviz_plugin/blob/table_widget_geometry/src/display_topics.cpp#L95

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285844/how-do-i-save-a-qbytearray-in-my-qt-panel?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-19**:
Not an answer, but I seem to remember RViz does something similar. Perhaps [VisualizationFrame::saveWindowGeometry(..)](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/2753be181daff8584eec4525efed182861c09c2d/src/rviz/visualization_frame.cpp#L841-L861) can provide some info / inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The example @gvdhoorn points helped me; the state must be saved as hexadecimal and then everything works as expected once you do the right conversions, the solution is:

Save:

```
void DisplayTopics::save(rviz::Config config) const
                         {
  rviz::Panel::save(config);

  QByteArray table_header_state(table_->horizontalHeader()->saveState());
  // Must be saved as hex
  config.mapSetValue("table_header_state", table_header_state.toHex());
}
```

Load:

```
void DisplayTopics::load(const rviz::Config& config)
{
  rviz::Panel::load(config);

  QString table_header_state_str;
  if (config.mapGetString("table_header_state", &table_header_state_str))
  {
    table_->horizontalHeader()->restoreState(QByteArray::fromHex(qPrintable(table_header_state_str)));
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-03-19**:
Full example is here: https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/topics_rviz_plugin/merge_requests/4/diffs